# Add Targets to Blackbox Exporter programmatically via API (Prometheus)

Tags: php, monitoring, prometheus, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

How can I add targets to blackbox exporter via an api or something similar?

Background
I created a small front end for status monitoring of websites, I am utilizing the blackbox exporter and created a simple interface for adding and removing targets (Bootstrap front, PHP backend). I couldn't find a programmatic way to manage targets so I'm add just editing the text and manually reloading the config via curl.

This *works* but is inconsistent, and restarts my probe times so it takes some time before I see the change. Wondering if anyone has experience doing it a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

The usual way to do this is to use the [FileSD](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#file_sd_config). This allows you to point to a directory or file which Prometheus will watch for changes.

The Workflow would be:

1. User changes Target
2. Your backend writes the target file in JSON format in the directory.
3. Prometheus picks up the changes and configures itself on the fly.